# C6001 - initialize memory with new?

Tags: c++, memory, initialization, new-operator

Here is my named pipe client sample code for sending a string to a named pipe server using Visual Studio 2019 with ISO C++ 14:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <strsafe.h>
void main()
{
DWORD cbRead = 0;
DWORD rv = ERROR_SUCCESS;
WCHAR *sPipename = new WCHAR [1024]();
WCHAR *chReadBuf = new WCHAR [1024]();
WCHAR *sMsgToSend = new WCHAR [1024]();

StringCchCopyW(sPipename, 1024, L"\\\\.\\pipe\\{23E0D6C2-A718-4C91-A81F-4069356686C5}");
StringCchCopy(sMsgToSend, 1024, L"test");
CallNamedPipeW(sPipename, sMsgToSend, (DWORD) (wcslen(sMsgToSend)+1)*sizeof(TCHAR), chReadBuf, 1024*sizeof(TCHAR), &cbRead, 5000);
}
```

I'm getting [C6001](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/code-quality/c6001?view=msvc-170) errors on the three variables in the function call, with the compiler showing a warning about not being initialized? They are initialized with parenthesis '( )'.

The suggested fix is to put a {} before the '=' sign. Which gives an error. I googled and searched but could not find an answer to this specific issue.

Thank you, any help is appreciated.

Comment: "C6001" is a compiler-specific error code that tells us nothing, unless we go and hunt it down.  Please show full error messages when asking about errors.

Comment: Given only these four lines, I cannot see how used-before-init can trigger here. Provide a proper [mcve] we can copy/paste/compile on your chosen toolchain (which should also be included in your question).

Comment: Which compiler are you using, and which C++ version are you compiling for? Also, `TCHAR` is the wrong type to use here, use `WCHAR` instead.

Comment: Your code seems fine (although you'd better have `WCHAR sPipename [1024] = {0};` instead of `WCHAR* sPipename = new WCHAR[1024]();`, using `new` here is pointless.). The problem must be elsewhere. Please provide a [mcve]. Also please show the __verbatim__ error log and make clear which lines of your code snippet they refer to

Comment: They are actually not being initialized. You are allocating the memory, but the memory itself remains uninitialized. After all, being a POD-Datatype, WCHAR has no constructor to perform automatic initialization upon allocation. Consider using automatic arrays `WCHAR sPipename[1024] = {}`

Comment: @RefugnicEternium The `()`s do zero-initialization.

Comment: This looks like yet another false positive from Microsoft's static analyzer.

Comment: @molbdnilo cannot reproduce with the MS static code analyser (Visual Studio 16.10.4).

Comment: They do, @molbdnilo? I was honest to goodness not aware of that. You learn something new every day, honestly.

Comment: Thank you for posting a [mcve]. The verbatim error log is still missing. Anyway, I could not reproduce this problem. Please tell us which version of the compiler you use and how you compile, compiler flags, Visual Studio Version, toolset used etc. and all relevant modes from Project>Properties.

Comment: Also: what happens if you replace `WCHAR *sPipename = new WCHAR [1024]();` with `WCHAR sPipename[1024] = {0};`? (Using `new` here is not wrong, but just pointless.

Comment: @Jabberwocky It's because this is a small snippet of the actual code, where there are tens of thousands of variables in all the functions and classes. I always use a pointer to minimize memory on the stack. Runtime Library is /MT, Warning Level is /W4

Comment: @molbdnilo It looks like the ( ) should initialize the array. In  ISO C++03 5.3.4[expr.new]/15 says "A new-expression that creates an object of type T initializes that object as follows: If the new-initializer is of the form (), the item is value-initialized (8.5)"

Comment: @JeffR using systematically new even for relatively small sizes (while not forgetting delete BTW) for saving stack space is a terrible idea. You can increment the stack size of your executable from the default 1Mb (which is not much) to say 8Mb. Anyway I am unable to reproduce the error you get. In the meantime, until you don't provide the information I asked for, in my previous comment, there is little we can do...

Comment: @Jabberwocky Thanks for your help, I appreciate it, and good points you made. I will go back and see what I can do.

Comment: I can't reproduce this with the current MSVC compiler or code analyser; however, using `WCHAR* sPipename = new WCHAR[1024]{ 0, };` may silence the warning. There are also other issues in your code: `main` should have `int` return type, not `void`, and you really shouldn't be using C-style casts.